# Why doesn't Lambert function (ProductLog) simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, inverse

I have

```
Simplify[ProductLog[x*Exp[x]]]
```

By the definition of the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), this should be simply x. But Mathematica outputs this:

```
ProductLog[E^x x]
```

Adding assumptions (e.g., x is real) does not help. Why doesn't Mathematica treat `ProductLog[x*Exp[x]]` as `x`, just like it treats `Log[Exp[x]]` as `x` (if `x` is real)? Due to this I cannot, e.g., verify some solutions that DSolve gave for a certain ODE, and this solution contained ProductLog. When I substitute that solution into the original ODE, I do not get zero identically, but instead a cumbersome expression, even after applying FullSimplify.

Answer (score 12):

The identity does not hold for x < -1:

```
Plot[ProductLog[x*Exp[x]], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
FullSimplify[ProductLog[x*Exp[x]], x >= -1]
```

> ```
> x    (* result in 10.1.0 under Windows *)
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
PowerExpand[ProductLog[x Exp[x]]]
```

> x

This assumes $x\ge0$

Comment: ...`PowerExpand[]` is dangerous to use in general, unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @J.M. Sure, but according to the documentation center, this is the correct way to simplify `ProductLog` expressions.

Comment: Yes, I'm merely giving the general reminder that one should not thoughtlessly use `PowerExpand[]`, in the same manner that one should not thoughtlessly simplify $\log \exp x$ to $x$.

Answer (score 5):

The equation

```
x Exp[x]  == y
```

has multiple solutions for `x`.

For example, evaluating

```
tab = Table[{x -> ProductLog[i, 1]}, {i, 0, 5}]
Exp[x] x /. tab
N[tab]
```

gives

```
{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
```

and

```
{{x -> 0.567143}, {x -> -1.53391 + 4.37519 I}, {x -> -2.40159 + 
10.7763 I}, {x -> -2.85358 + 17.1135 I}, {x -> -3.16295 + 
23.4277 I}, {x -> -3.39869 + 29.7313 I}}
```

Therefore, it would be potentially incorrect to simplify `Simplify[ProductLog[x*Exp[x]]]` to `x`